# What does "@path\" mean on the command line?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-server-2008

This may be a nubish question, but I am Googling around for this and do not see the answer so far.  Take the following command:

```
at 12:00 /EVERY:Su Forfiles.exe -p C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1 -m *.log -d
-30 -c \"Cmd.exe /C del @path\"
```

I know what the expected behavior of this overall command is, and I know what each part of it is doing - except for the "@path\" thing.  Googling it isn't turning up results so far.  What does this mean?  I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@path - returns the full path of the file,

In general is the removal of the Log Folders IIS server, but why?)))

run at cmd (Windows 2008 R2):

```
Forfiles -p C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1 -m *.log -d -30 -c "cmd /C @echo @path"
Forfiles -p C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1 -m *.log -c "cmd /C @echo @path"
```

run at cmd Windows 7 as sample:

```
Forfiles -p %windir%\inf -m *.inf -c "cmd /C @echo @path"
Forfiles -p %windir%\inf -m *.inf -d -30 -c "cmd /C @echo @path"
```

Comment: An output of these commands might be useful to prove your point, at least an abbreviated one.

Comment: @KronoS If possible, to edit my post for a better view, thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  The reason I was wanting to get rid of them is that the space that folder takes up can get pretty ridiculous over a period of time.

Comment: @Panzercrisis Perhaps the best idea will seem compress files for subsequent removal. Glad I could help you.